# Text typing with animation using setTimeout() doesn't working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I tried to write a program that is typing text in the field with animation. But it does not work. WHY???

```
var str = "SuperUser";
var i = 0;
var inp = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

function enter(str, elem, i){
   elem.value += str[i];
   i++;
   setTimeout(enter(str, inp, i), getRandomInt(500, 2000))
}
setTimeout(enter(str, inp, i), getRandomInt(500, 2000))

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

Error screenshot:

[image: JS console error on chrome browser]

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". Also, describe what you want your code to do, and what it does instead. Then you need to learn the difference between function call and function reference.

Comment: And don't include just a screenshot of the error, copy the actual error text into your question, so that the search can index it properly and other users find it

Comment: The best option is to `bind` the arguments to the `enter` function.

`enter.bind(this, str, inp, i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 setTimeout(enter(str, inp, i), getRandomInt(500, 2000));
```

This doesnt work. It executes the **return value** at the Timeout,do this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 enter(str,inp,i);
},1000);
```

Also, in your enter you need to stop somewhere. Add into the first line:

```
if(i>=str.length){return;}
```

By the way, you dont need to pass the variables as theyre in the global scope:

```
enter();
```

All together:

```
window.onload=function(){
 var str = "SuperUser"; 
 var i = 0; 
 var inp = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]; 
  function enter(){
    if(i>=str.length){return;}
    inp.value += str[i];
    i++;
    setTimeout(enter, getRandomInt(500, 2000)); 
} 
enter();
function getRandomInt(min, max) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; }
};
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `enter(str, inp, i)` function recursively. that's why it is exceeding the stack memory. **There is no termination condition**

```js
var str = "SuperUser";
var i = 0;
var inp = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

function enter(str, elem, i){
   elem.value += str[i];
   i++;
   setTimeout(enter(str, inp, i), getRandomInt(500, 2000));
}
enter(str, inp, i);

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```